# tap action on UICollectionView's cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want a cell in UICollectionView can be tapped(not selected,because selected cell would be add to the `[cllectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]`), what means: when I tap a cell I can show a detail view of the cell and it would **not** be add to `[cllectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]`.

Comment: and I not using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this at this time -- other than to deselect the item after the selection is made.  I spent a lot of time trying to make this happen and it just doesn't work.

The problem is this: You have to get hold of the default gesture recognizer for the collectionView tap to require it to fail, and you can't.  Apple gives some instructions, but they don't work as advertised.  See page 36 of:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf

The problem is that the sample code in this article doesn't work.  On inspecting the default gesture recognizers, you'll find there isn't one of the class type UITapGesureRecognizer.  It may be you can figure out what's going on with it, but I never could (if you figure it out, I'd sure like to know how to do it).

Ultimately, everyone workaround I tried failed, and I ended up having to settle for using a long press.  There are some other posts on this subject, but I never could find anything else that actually worked.  This was all on iOS 6.0.

Someone had also asked about using a double tap, and I could not get the select to consistently fail on that.  At first I thought that was the solution, but found that it would sporadically select the cell that was double-tapped, and with no other workaround had to move to the long press, which seemed to work.  In the end I had to scrap that work for other reasons, so I never put it in production.

Hope you can find a solution but my experience was not good.